# Install Firefox on Tinycore (Docker)

Tags: linux, firefox, docker

How do you install Firefox on Linux Tinycore on a Docker container?

Normally on debian you would go ahead and write in the Dockerfile:

```
RUN deb http://packages.linuxmint.com debian import
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install firefox
```

but since `deb` is not available on Tinycore, how would you do this in the Dockerfile?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into (*for example*): [CRUX X-Chat](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/crux/xchat/) -- Aside from the differences in Linux dsitribution the you'll want to use the same (*if not similar*) concepts to get X/Xorg apps running inside Docker containers.

The main points are:

- Install Firefox and all X/Xorg dependeninces as part of your `RUN` command in your `Dockerfile`
- Run the following and/or create a shell script or function to wrap this up nicely:

  export XSOCK=/tmp/.X11-unix
  export XAUTH=/tmp/.docker.xauth

  if [ ! -f $XAUTH ]; then
      touch $XAUTH
      xauth nlist :0 | sed -e "s/^..../ffff/" | xauth -f $XAUTH nmerge -
  fi

  docker run -i -t -e DISPLAY -e USER -e XAUTHORITY=$XAUTH -v $XSOCK:$XSOCK -v $XAUTH:$XAUTH --net=host